# How to set custom keyword for node project?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, newman

if i published my project, i can get through

```
npm i <myproject>
```

if i want to use, i need to call like

```
./nodemodules/myproject [arg0] [arg1]
```

or

```
npx myproject [arg0] [arg1]
```

but i don't want to call ./node.. or npx
instead
i want to use custom keyword to call my project like **newman**

If you see this project : https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman

they are simply calling

```
newman run colname environment
```

no where they are using

> ./nodemodules/newman or npx newman

likewise,
i want custom keyword that should recognize mine
./nodemodules/myproject

suggest me how newman did this ? or suggest how to achieve this ?

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-json#bin

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-and-publishing-scoped-public-packages

Comment: @jonrsharpe i added the bin too
"bin": {
    "my-package": "out/index.js"
  }
.......... if i call "my-package", i am getting the error - is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: Are you installing it _globally_? If not, as the docs say, it's linked to `./node_modules/.bin` (which is added to the path when you `npm run` a script).

Comment: let me install it globally and try it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you so much. this should not be installed locally. please add this as comment. people can upvote. it is working for me now after installing it globally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Global installation resolved the issue, Thank you @jonrsharpe. New module exposed in npm registry

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/jaiman